# Altering format.date in bst to place parentheses around year

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I would like to add parentheses to the year in the bibliography of a paper (i.e., Kyle, A. S. (1985). etc.).  Unfortunately, the journal .bst file is not quite correct on this point.  The link to the .bst file is at:
http://rfssfs.org/files/2012/09/RFS-BibTeX-style-file-010414.pdf

I have been unsuccessful altering the format.date function to accomplish this based on related questions.  Below is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper,doublespacing]{article} 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\makeatother 
\usepackage{ntheorem} 
    \RequirePackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,xcolor,graphicx,natbib,booktabs,geometry,chngcntr,comment,array,dcolumn,subfig, lscape, longtable}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,labelsep=newline]{caption}  %Make Table and Figure bold
\theoremstyle{plain}  %COMMENTED 10/6/14

\begin{document}
\cite{Kyle_Econ_1985} is a seminal paper.

\bibliographystyle{rfs}
\bibliography{mwe_bib}

\end{document}
```

Here is the .bib entry:

```
@ARTICLE{Kyle_Econ_1985,
  author = {Kyle, Albert S.},
  title = {Continuous Auctions and Insider Trading},
  journal = {Econometrica},
  year = {1985}, 
  volume = {53},
  pages = {1315--1336},
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace the date function with:

```
FUNCTION {format.date}
  { year empty$
      { "" }
      { year "(" swap$ * ")" *}
    if$
  }
```

[image]

Comment: This worked.  Thanks.  I kept the `extra.label *`, `before.all 'output.state :=` and `after.sentence  'output.state :=` at the end of the function.

Answer (score 1):

A modification of user2478's proposal that will remove the comma between the authors and the year and keep the extra label (a, b in case of multiple entries with the same year) inside the brackets:

```
FUNCTION {format.date}
  { year empty$
    { "" }
    { year " (" swap$ * extra.label * ")" *}
  if$
  before.all 'output.state :=
  }
```